# Go to wrksplf after exit from DSPF?

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

I'm creating a screen designer on iSeries 400 [IBM]

The RPGLE program that I create I'm trying to find out what will be the command to let the user be in the `wrksplf` after they exit from the program (press F3 that I create indicator)

in CLLE I can just use `wrksplf` at the end of the program before `enddo` but I can't find any information how to do that in the other languages like RPGLE or anything else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you are in an interactive job, you can just call QCMDEXC to invoke the command ...

```
DQCMDEXC          PR                  EXTPGM('QCMDEXC')    
D prCmdStr                    4096A   CONST                
D prCmdLen                      15P 5 CONST                

 /free
  QCMDEXC('WRKSPLF':25);
 /end-free
```

Comment: Just to clarify... You can use QCMDEXC in batch or interactive jobs, but you would probably only want to use WRKSPLF interactively.

Answer (score 1):

ILE programs / procedures can call ILE procedures written in other languages.  Calling a compiled CLLE procedure containing a command is more efficient than calling the QCMDEXC interpreter interface to parse and execute it. It also enables you to encapsulate more functionality in the called procedure, in cases where that may be helpful.

You could create a simple CLLE module to perform the WRKSPLF command.  Your ILE RPG can CALLP to the CL procedure. You can create your program [CRTPGM] with both the RPG and CL modules.  Or you can create your program with the RPG module, and create a service program [CRTSRVPGM] with the CL. This method may be preferable in cases where your CL might be used by other programs in the future.